# Scroll com animate não funciona

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

O código abaixo em jQuery roda perfeitamente bem no Google Chrome e Opera. O problema é que não funciona no IE e Firefox, antes funcionava.

```
// Jquery document...
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function (event) {
        var id = $(this).attr("href");
        var target = $(id).offset().top - 200;

        $('body').animate({scrollTop:target}, 300);
        event.preventDefault (); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em alguns navegadores o scrollBar fica no body e em outros fica no html, portanto você deve mudar o seletor para:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:target}, 300);
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function (event) {
        var id = $(this).attr("href");
        var target = $(id).offset().top - 200;

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:target}, 300);
        event.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Valeu Guilherme, funcionou.